# Setting a temporary cookie to an invalid value when logout improves security?

Tags: cookies, session-management

When a session is closed, for example, when a timeout triggers or when the user clicks the logout button, the session should be terminated at server side so the session cookie is invalid.

I think that it could be useful to also set to a blank or invalid value the session cookie in the browser, even if it is a temporary cookie. For example, when you click the Logout button the server could answer with a Set-Cookie that sets an invalid value for the cookie.

**Does this measure improve the security of the site or is this "too much" having into account that the cookie is temporary and the session is closed correctly in server-side?**

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately with a web application, the security should always reside at the server-side, and as such the important measure when a user is logged out of an application is to ensure that the session is no longer valid on the server-side.

I don't think that there's any harm in invalidating the session on the client-side as well, it might be useful to reduce load on the server as it doesn't need to do a look-up on the session ID to see if it's valid or perhaps to improve user experience in quickly routing a user to the login page.

However setting it on the client-side should not be considered a security measure.